# bash: /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/mongo: Permission denied [MongoDB 4.4 set up on AWS cloud 9 IDE]

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, cloud9-ide

I'm trying to install Mongodb version 4.4 on a AWS IDE (using a Mac and Ubuntu set up). I receive the following error message:

```
bash: /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/mongo: Permission denied
```

It seems it's a permission issue, however I have no idea to to rectify this. Any ideas or steps to take to resolve this?

Comment: In the future add steps you took to do the install as well as present articles talking about the issue to show your due diligence. A google of your error "/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/mongo: Permission denied" reveals potential solutions as well as the answer provided by Felipe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems there is already a discussion about this error on the MongoDB forum.

Here is the [link](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-45021)

They closed it as **Won't fix**.

The final answer was provided by Mathew Robinson as:

> Closing this as Won't Fix, it seems that Linuxbrew is a very small
> subset of homebrew users and we support from source builds as well as
> Linux packages for all distributions we support.
>
> In the case of Linuxbrew it would just be a way to run our from source
> builds that we already document how to do.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem

the problem is that you use homebrew and the files are in a restricted area which means Linux can't modify it.

I solved it by:

full this guide to Install MongoDB Community Edition :

```
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/
```

then, instead of using `mongod` use `mongosh` which allows you to add data to the table.

I tried `mongod` and it never works and I don't know why.

it give `aborting after fassert() failure\n\n"}` so `mongosh` work fine.